# RecylerView won't populate

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

UPDATE AFTER DEBUGGING

It turns out that `convertCursorToTransactionInfoList` and `transactionLoadComplete` are never actually running. I put break points on them and they never showed up in the debugger. Also, `adapterData: size = 0` is showing when running the debugger.

I was able to properly populate ONE ITEM of the recycler view using the code in `onCreateView` under `TransactionInfo returnListValue = new TransactionInfo();`

Can anyone provide some insight into why this wouldn't be working? The more and more I do this, I'm thinking it has to do with either `ArrayList<>` and `List<>` descrepancies because `ArrayList<>` is used in `TransactionsTab.java` whereas in `AdapterTransactions.java`, `List<>` is used *OR* `TransactionInfo.java` in some aspect. I've posted all of these classes below.

The SQLite interface isn't the problem (I'm pretty sure) as I'm using it elsewhere in the app to populate `Spinners` using `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

TransactionsTab.java:

```
public class TransactionsTab extends Fragment
    implements TransactionLoad.LoadComplete {

RecyclerView transactionsRecycler;
AdapterTransactions adapter;
TransactionLoad load = null;
Cursor cursor;
ArrayList<TransactionInfo> adapterData = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    load = new TransactionLoad(getActivity());
    load.execute();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_transactions,container,false);
    transactionsRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.transactionRecycler);
    adapter = new AdapterTransactions(getActivity(), adapterData);
    transactionsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    transactionsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    TransactionInfo returnListValue = new TransactionInfo();
    returnListValue.itemName = "lunch";
    returnListValue.itemCat = "Food";
    returnListValue.itemCurrency = "KRW";
    returnListValue.itemPrice = "125";
    returnListValue.date = "2015/08/25; 17:25:32";
    adapterData.add(returnListValue);

    return view;
}

private void convertCursorToTransactionInfoList(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            TransactionInfo returnListValue = new TransactionInfo();
            returnListValue.itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NAME));
            returnListValue.itemCat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY));
            returnListValue.itemCurrency = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY));
            returnListValue.itemPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_PRICE));
            returnListValue.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE));
            adapterData.add(returnListValue);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void transactionLoadComplete(Cursor cursor) {
    convertCursorToTransactionInfoList(cursor);
    adapter.setData(adapterData);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.transactionData.notifyAll();
}
}
```

AdapterTransactions.java:

```
public class AdapterTransactions extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTransactions.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<TransactionInfo> transactionData = Collections.emptyList();

public void setData(List<TransactionInfo> newData) {
    transactionData = newData;
}

public AdapterTransactions(Context context, List<TransactionInfo> transactionData) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.transactionData = transactionData;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TransactionInfo current = transactionData.get(position);
    holder.itemName.setText(current.itemName);
    holder.itemCat.setText(current.itemCat);
    holder.itemPrice.setText(current.itemPrice);
    holder.itemDate.setText(current.date);
    holder.itemCurrency.setText(current.itemCurrency);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return transactionData.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView itemName, itemCat, itemPrice, itemDate, itemCurrency;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        itemCat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCat);
        itemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);
        itemDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDate);
        itemCurrency = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCurrency);
    }
}
}
```

TransactionInfo.java:

```
public class TransactionInfo {
public String itemName, itemPrice, itemCurrency, itemCat, date;
}
```

**RE ANSWERS:**

I've tried the following method alterations to `convertCursorToTransactionInfoList`:

```
private void convertCursorToTransactionInfoList(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            TransactionInfo returnListValue = new TransactionInfo();
            returnListValue.itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NAME));
            returnListValue.itemCat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY));
            returnListValue.itemCurrency = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY));
            returnListValue.itemPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_PRICE));
            returnListValue.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE));
            adapterData.add(returnListValue);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
private static void convertCursorToTransactionInfoList(Cursor cursor, ArrayList<TransactionInfo> adapterData) {
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            TransactionInfo returnListValue = new TransactionInfo();
            returnListValue.itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NAME));
            returnListValue.itemCat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY));
            returnListValue.itemCurrency = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY));
            returnListValue.itemPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_PRICE));
            returnListValue.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE));
            adapterData.add(returnListValue);
        }
    }
}
```

with notifying adatpers like this:

```
@Override
public void transactionLoadComplete(Cursor cursor) {
    convertCursorToTransactionInfoList(cursor, adapterData);
    adapter.setData(adapterData);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.transactionData.notifyAll();
}
```

Also, note taht I had to change `List<TransactionInfo> adapterData = new ArrayList<>();` to `ArrayList<TransactionInfo> adapterData = new ArrayList<>();`

The more I look at this the more I think it has to do with `ArrayList<>` or `List<>` issues.

**END EDIT**

Comment: Where does it stop working?  Are you getting results from the db?  Is it creating views that aren't showing up?

Comment: The fragments are just blank; there's nothing being displayed. The database has the necessary transactions to load if that's what you mean by getting results. I'm not sure how to check for created views.

Comment: use debug or [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class instead of posting whole app code...

Comment: Oh I see what you guys mean. I've added DDMS LogCat to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with getting the data out of the `Cursor`, specifically here:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    for (int i = 10; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        returnListValue.itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NAME));
        returnListValue.itemCat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY));
        returnListValue.itemCurrency = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY));
        returnListValue.itemPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_PRICE));
        returnListValue.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE));
        returnList.add(returnListValue);
    }
}
```

Your code above moves the cursor to the first position (`cursor.moveToFirst()`) but after that the `Cursor` position doesn't change so your loop is executed `cursor.getCount()` times but it only operates on the first item in the cursor.

Instead, I would opt for a while loop instead of a for loop, like this:

```
// move cursor on to next position if available
while(cursor.moveToNext()) { 
    // More data is available so add it to the list
    // process data as before
}
```

## EDIT 1

RE [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008455/recylerview-wont-populate/34012059?noredirect=1#comment55803712_34012059) - here's what I suggest changing.

Instead of:

```
adapterData = convertCursorToBudgetInfoList(cursor);
```

Either:

### Option 1

`convertCursorToBudgetInfoList` remains a `static` method but now operates on the original `adapterData` reference.

```
convertCursorToBudgetInfoList(cursor, adapterData);
```

and change your method to:

```
private static void convertCursorToBudgetInfoList(Cursor cursor, ArrayList<TransactionInfo> adapterData) {

    if (cursor != null) {                         

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { // note: no for loop ;-)
            TransactionInfo returnListValue = new TransactionInfo();
            returnListValue.itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NAME));
            returnListValue.itemCat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY));
            returnListValue.itemCurrency = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY));
            returnListValue.itemPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_PRICE));
            returnListValue.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE));
            adapterData.add(returnListValue);
        }
    }
}
```

### Option 2

Make `convertCursorToBudgetInfoList` a member method instead of static and operate on your `adapterData` directly.

```
convertCursorToBudgetInfoList(cursor);
```

and change your method to:

```
private void convertCursorToBudgetInfoList(Cursor cursor) {

    if (cursor != null) {                         

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { // note: no for loop ;-)
            TransactionInfo returnListValue = new TransactionInfo();
            returnListValue.itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NAME));
            returnListValue.itemCat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY));
            returnListValue.itemCurrency = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY));
            returnListValue.itemPrice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_PRICE));
            returnListValue.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE));
            adapterData.add(returnListValue); // member variable (same as this.adapterData)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, with either of these options make sure to notify your adapter.

I would also reiterate that you really need to get rid of that `for` loop - step through it with a debugger and all will become clear.

Comment: so I changed `if` to `while` like you suggested, but it still doesn't display anything. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've been looking into it and came to the same realisation as @n00bean who has just answered. `adapterData = convertCursorToBudgetInfoList(cursor);` does not update the adapter's reference to the data. Either do as @n00bean suggests or pass `convertCursorToBudgetInfoList` a reference to the original `adapterData` and do the `List.add()` calls on it instead of statically.

Comment: unfortunately, none of those options worked :( oh man is this getting frustrating :\

Comment: updated the OP again, maybe you or @n00bean can make sense of it better than me.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this `for` loop within `convertCursorToBudgetInfoList`:

```
for (int i = 10; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
```

to start at `0`...  if there are less than 10 results nothing will show up!

Comment: haha, I thought that was to set the max length. I switched it to `0`, but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in TransactionsTab. In the  transactionLoadComplete(Cursor cursor) method you update the Fragments List transactionData but you never pass this onto your RecyclerView Adapter. So calling notify on your adapter does nothing as it's data hasn't changed.

Your solution would be to create a function in your Adapter such as:

```
public void setData(List<TransactionData> newData){
    transactionData = newData;
}
```

Then call the new function before notifyDataSetChanged in transactionLoadComplete(Cursor cursor):

```
public void transactionLoadComplete(Cursor cursor) {
    adapterData = convertCursorToBudgetInfoList(cursor);
    adapter.setData(adapterData);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.transactionData.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: Can you update all code in your answer to what you are now using? I just spotted your for loop starts with int i = 10 but not sure if you changed that part already as suggested by @aoemerson in his answer.

Comment: Just updated it. The only change I made was the one Buddy suggested. I did try aoemerson's answer, but nothing worked, so I reverted back to what I originally had. I tried it both ways with your suggestions, but neither worked.

Comment: Your `for` loop as it stands effectively does nothing but repeat the same logic for the first item in the `Cursor` so I would definitely change that to be honest. Set a break point in your debugger and step through the loop to see what I mean.

Comment: aoemerson is correct, however there is something else not working right, otherwise you would see the first element displayed cursor.getCount() times in the view. Throw in break points everywhere, especially in the RecycleView Adapter and see what that is attempting to do with the data you supply it. Is it getting the correct item count and adding them to a recycler view that cannot be seen or is it displaying the recycler view with nothing in it?